# kaminari AJAX load more button won't work

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, kaminari, slim-lang

I've noticed how Akira Matsuda have added helper in Kaminari gem and made ti a lot simple for us to use Load more button.

I've read the document and figured simply adding

```
<%= link_to_next_page @items, 'Next Page' %>
```

should make the ajax load button work, but id didn't.
So I googled few other articles for some help and I wrote
few extra things...

Here are what I have right now.

I have these files

root.html.slim

```
  ul#works
    = render :partial => "works"
```

work.html.slim

```
- @works.each do | work |
  = link_to work
    li
      span.thumb
        = work_image_of work
    h4 = link_to work.title, work, thumb:true
    p.pull-left
      small
        = work.collaborators.count.to_s
        |&nbsp;collaborators

= link_to_next_page @works, 'Next Page', id: 'view_more'
```

index.controller

```
    def root
      @works = Work.page(params[:page]).per(9)
      render :layout => 'application'
    end
```

also added in application.js

```
$('#works').append("<%= escape_javascript(render 'works', object: @works) %>");

$("#view_more").replaceWith("<%= escape_javascript(
    link_to_next_page(@works, 'more', remote: true, id: 'view_more')
) %>");
```

and this in action helper,

```
  def link_to_next_page(scope, name, options = {}, &block)
    param_name = options.delete(:param_name) || Kaminari.config.param_name
    link_to_unless scope.last_page?, name, {param_name => (scope.current_page + 1)}, options.merge(:rel => 'next') do
      block.call if block
    end
  end
```

I have jquery included in my js files.
What am I missing? 
Please help me out!

Thank you for your time!!

Comment: Have you taken a look at: https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/wiki/How-To:-Create-Infinite-Scrolling-with-jQuery

Comment: No, I have not. I'll take a look.

Comment: It looks to me like what you're missing is the equivalent of the very last coffeescript on that page. Basically, you need a javascript that runs when the user scrolls to bottom of the page.

Comment: thanks for the tip, but I dont want the app to automatically load more post when users scroll to bottom of the page. I want the button to trigger the action. Is coffee script still the problem that needs to be solved?